# Prevent table row from growing (ie keep a fixed row height) for an html table using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple table control that I have created using javascript dynamically when the website runs.

I have fixed widths for the columns using the bootstrap classes (eg `col-xs-3` etc).

One of the columns in the table is a description field for which there are many entries in my data with longer text.

On a large screen it is just a single line of text so everything is fine, but when reducing the size of the window, and when using smaller devices, the width is too narrow to show the description on a single line and so will wrap around and cause the whole row to grow to fit the entire text.

Showing the entire text is not a requirement and I need to make sure the table row doesn't grow and stays a fixed height no matter the screen/window size.

Is there a way to do this in css as I do not want to insert an extra div within each cell element if i can avoid it, which i have already seen suggested on other posts.

Also, this needs to be compatible with safari and chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    max-width: 200px;   //or adjust for however wide you want max width to be, 
                        //could also use % widths like max-width: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This will create a `...` whenever the text is wider than the table cell.

Comment: I've searched this question a lot, and this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.tr {
max-height: 50px;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: A small sentence to explain would not be overkill :)

Comment: @Drax: Explain what? It is self-explanatory. Another sentence would just be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `text-overflow` to the `td` element, to hide the content when it overflows the size. You just have to set a `max-width` to it...

Also, set the property `white-space:nowrap` to keep all the text in a single line.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ev7227bd/